# arcsin x function in pgfplots with normal axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

This is my code for asin x (picture on the left):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[domain = -1:1, samples = 500]
    \addplot[color = red]  {asin(x)/180*pi};
      \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: I get the one one the left, but i want the axes like i drew on the right]

I get the one one the left, but i want the axes like i drew on the right.
Her is the code i made for the axes i want:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=2*1.56cm,y=2cm]
  \draw[->] (-1.05,0) -- (1.05,0);
  \draw[->] (0,-1.7) -- (0,1.7);

  \draw (-0.03,1.57) -- (0.03,1.57);
  \draw (-0.08,1.57) node {\footnotesize{$\frac{\pi}{2}$}};
  \draw (-0.03,-1.57) -- (0.03,-1.57);
  \draw (-0.12,-1.57) node {\footnotesize{$-\frac{\pi}{2}$}};

  \draw (1,-0.05) -- (1,0.05);
  \draw (1,-0.15) node {\footnotesize{$1$}};
  \draw (-1,-0.05) -- (-1,0.05);
  \draw (-1,-0.15) node {\footnotesize{$-1$}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please post a complete minimal example, so we can see all of your setup as well. Assuming some default setup, you can have the axis lines in the middle with the `axis lines*=middle` option. The `xtick`s and `ytick`s are set with their respective keys, and you can set the labels on the y-axis using the `yticklabels` key:

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[domain=-1:1, samples=500, axis lines*=middle, xtick={-1,1}, ytick={-1.57,1.57}, yticklabels={$-\pi$/2,$\pi$/2}]
    \addplot[color = red]  {asin(x)/180*pi};
      \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! But is it possible to let the markings on the y-axis be pi/2 and -pi/2 instead of 1 and -1?

Comment: Do you want the markings at that location, or simply to be labeled that way?

Comment: the x-axis is fine but i would like the markings as i made them i the second tikzpicture code in my question

Comment: The fix is simple... add `ytick={-1.57, 1.57}, yticklabels={$-\pi/2$, $\pi/2$}` to the axis options, see the edit

Comment: Yeah i probably should have posted a picture of that too i guess. But this is exactly what i wanted! Thank you very much!